# Pythagoras' formula in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm very beginner at programming. I try to make Pythagoras' formula with javascript. I can't explain it very well in English, so can you try it by yourself and see what's wrong with my codes and how to fix it?

Here's the code:

```js
var a = document.getElementById("a").innerHTML;
var b = document.getElementById("b").innerHTML;
var c = document.getElementById("c").innerHTML;

function fungsi(x) {
  c = sqrt(a * a + b * b)
};

function fungsi(y) {
  a = sqrt(c * c - b * b)
};

function fungsi(z) {
  b = sqrt(c * c - a * a)
};
if (c = null) {
  getElementById("tombol").onclick = fungsi(x);
} else if (a = null) {
  getElementById("tombol").onclick = fungsi(y);
} else {
  getElementById("tombol").onclick = fungsi(z);
}
```

```html
<input id="a" type=number>
<br>
<input id="b" type=number>
<br>
<input id="c" type=number>
<br>
<button id="tombol" onclick=fungsi()>hitung</button>
```

Comment: I think there is a fundamental issue here in that you haven't got the basic Javascript skills down just yet. Start off on a tutorial, then work your way to solving your formula. There are almost too many issues here to fix in one answer.

Comment: 1. You should use `.value`, not `.innerHTML` to get value of an input, 2. you're re-declaring the `fungsi` function twice, 3. `sqrt` is not a global function, it's a method of the `Math` object, so `Math.sqrt(...)`, 4. `getElementById` should be `document.getElementById`...

Comment: 5. `if (c = null)` is an *assignment*, not an equality check and will always return false. 6. `fungsi` has already been assigned as the `onclick` handler in the HTML. 7. `x`, `y` and`z` are undefined. 8. `onclick = fungsi(x)` will assign `undefined` to the `onclick` handler as `fungsi` doesn't return a value. There are more.

Comment: too many issues? :D.. yeah, I should learn more.. but thanks alot for your comments, it's all really help! All I need is teacher, who told me what's wrong with my codes, just like you guys do! I think it's too hard for me to learn it by myself.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BECAUSE YOU TRIED (and SO many don't even bother):

Your HTML:

```
<input id="a" type=number>
<br>
<input id="b" type=number>
<br>
<input id="c" type=number>
<br>
<button id="tombol" onclick="fungsi()">hitung</button>
```

Your Javascript:

```
function fungsi()
{
    var vals = {};

    if( document.getElementById("a").value.length > 0 )
    {
        vals.a = document.getElementById("a").value;
    }
    if( document.getElementById("b").value.length > 0 )
    {
        vals.b = document.getElementById("b").value;
    }
    if( document.getElementById("c").value.length > 0 )
    {
        vals.c = document.getElementById("c").value;
    }

    if( Object.keys(vals).length < 2 )
    {
        alert('Need 2 values');
        return;
    }

    if( typeof vals.a != 'undefined' && typeof vals.b != 'undefined' )
    {
        alert( ( Math.sqrt( vals.a * vals.a + vals.b * vals.b ) ) );
    }
    else if( typeof vals.b != 'undefined' && typeof vals.c != 'undefined' )
    {
        alert( ( Math.sqrt( vals.b * vals.b + vals.c * vals.c ) ) );
    }
    else if( typeof vals.a != 'undefined' && typeof vals.c != 'undefined' )
    {
        alert( ( Math.sqrt( vals.a * vals.a + vals.c * vals.c ) ) );
    }
}
```

Should be enough to give you a push ;)

Comment: Thanks ALOT!!! I've tried it, but it's not what I'm supposed to.. You know phytagoras is>> c² = a² + b². Your codes give correct answer when we want to search the value of "c". But it give wrong answer when we want to search the value of "a", or "b".

Comment: Then fix it - you know you want to ;)

Comment: Yes, I've fixed it and it works..I just changed>> else if( typeof vals.b != 'undefined' && typeof vals.c != 

'undefined' )
    {
        alert( ( Math.sqrt( vals.c * vals.c - vals.b * vals.b ) ) 

);
    }
    else if( typeof vals.a != 'undefined' && typeof vals.c != 

'undefined' )
    {
        alert( ( Math.sqrt( vals.c * vals.c - vals.a * vals.a ). >>>>> Yeah I need to learn ALOT more.. alot of method I don't understand yet.. :D

Comment: There are a few basics there for you to work from and look up in documentation.  How to get the value of an input element ... how to create an object containing values (vals) ... how to check the number of elements in an object ... how to exit script execution (return).  I want to wish you all the best as you embark upon what I hope will be a joyful, rewarding journey for you.  It has been for me :)

Comment: I've visit w3schools.com recently, it really help me understand the basics. But there's too much things there, I think I need direction to find what I need. And your comment here is really,really HELPFUL!! By your comment about how to create an object containing values, I google it and found EXACTLY what I need to know! Thank you!!! Wish you all the BEST!

Answer (score 1):

For Pythagore function I just wrote this if it helps.

```js
function pythagore(a, b, hypoth) {
    let result;
    let ab = [a, b];
    if(hypoth === null) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2));
    } else if (a === null || b === null) {
        ab = ab[0] || ab[1];
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(hypoth, 2) - Math.pow(ab, 2));
    }
}
console.log(pythagore(5, null, 13))
// Expected output : 12
```